# Convert Spark data frame into array of JSON objects

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following Dataframe as an example:

```
+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------------+
|               user_id                |    city    | user_name  |   facebook_id    |
+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------------+
| 55c3c59d-0163-46a2-b495-bc352a8de883 | Toronto    | username_x | 0123482174440907 |
| e2ddv22d-4132-c211-4425-9933aa8de454 | Washington | username_y | 0432982476780234 |
+--------------------------------------+------------+------------+------------------+
```

How can I convert it to an array of JSON Objecta like:

```
[{
  "user_id": "55c3c59d-0163-46a2-b495-bc352a8de883",
  "facebook_id": "0123482174440907"
},
{
  "user_id": "e2ddv22d-4132-c211-4425-9933aa8de454",
  "facebook_id": "0432982476780234"
}]
```

Comment: `df.select("user_id", "facebook_id").toJSON` should be your answer

Comment: @RameshMaharjan but how can I have it as String, your solution return datraframe, I want to use it as a String in the Body of my HTTP request

Comment: please see my answer below. It returns you an array of string.. which will serve the purpose you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already loaded the given data in the form of a dataframe, you can use  function toJSON on the dataframe.

```
*scala> sc.parallelize(Seq(("55c3c59d-0163-46a2-b495-bc352a8de883","Toronto","username_x","0123482174440907"))).toDF("user_id","city","user_name","facebook_id")
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [user_id: string, city: string, user_name: string, facebook_id: string]*


*res2.toJSON.take(1)
res3: Array[String] = Array({"user_id":"55c3c59d-0163-46a2-b495-bc352a8de883","city":"Toronto","user_name":"username_x","facebook_id":"0123482174440907"})*
```

Comment: Is there a way to store the output as an array of json objects to a output?  I tried to write the toJson object to an output location using saveAsTextFile(), but am getting a text file of individual json objects, not an array?  I am looking for a file with the above result set provided by the original post.  Thanks